# Maven: Failed to read artifact descriptor for

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I am writing project in `Java` using `Maven` for dependecines and I put on my own maven server lib for client api `maven@server:~/public/com/iggroup/publicapi/client/java/api-client-sdk-2.0.5.jar` and created in the same location `.pom` file which looks like below

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.iggroup.publicapi.client.java</groupId>
  <artifactId>api-client-sdk</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.5</version>
</project>
```

... and in my project `pom.xml` file I add dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.iggroup.publicapi.client.java</groupId>
    <artifactId>api-client-sdk</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Maven was refreshed, found correct version but can't load this lib and shows `Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.iggroup.publicapi.client.java:api-client-sdk:jar:2.0.5`

Lib is OK but maybe I do something wrong with name file, paths or my pom ?

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution. Path in server was wrong, should looks like below:
`maven@server:~/public/com/iggroup/publicapi/client/java/api-client-sdk/2.0.5/api-client-sdk-2.0.5.jar`